# How to filter an array with multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, angular, filter, angular7

How can I filter an array with multiple parameters? What is wrong with this code:

```
let tmpArray = [{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"},{"id":"3"}];
this.nodes = tmpArray.filter(x => {
    return x.id.toString() == "1" && x.id.toString() == "2";
  });
```

In this case I would like it to return an array of objects with id 1 and 2...

Comment: There us no `pageTypeId` in `tmpArray ` & `toString() `is redundant

Comment: use  `||` not `&&`;

Comment: Omg! Thank you Vladimir! Overlooked that one.

Comment: But I don’t understand the hate on this question. I guess it is a legit Q if you don’t want to use a Pipe and filter that way.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You don't have pageTypeId property in the object. Because of that, i changed this property to id in the statement, and if you want filter value 1 or 2, i used || characters. Maybe you will edit your code like this, it will work.

```
let tmpArray = [{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"},{"id":"3"}];
this.nodes = tmpArray.filter(x => {
    return x.id.toString() == "1" || x.id.toString() == "2";
});
```

Comment: The missing `pageTypeId` indicates that the OP's code is missing something. That something could have been a problem when writing this question, or it could be the original problem. We don't know, and that makes this question unanswerable. Other than that, I'd suggest always explaining _what_ you changed, and why.

Comment: Yepp. PageTypeId is my bad. I copy/pasted some code and changed it in the stack editor. Have updated the code.

Comment: Anyway, it is the || that does the trick. Embarrasing to overlook that one 

Comment: @Cerbrus sorry about that. I changed my answer.

Comment: I'm happy if I could help you @TommyF.